# Variable value is read before an API request (which changes its value)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to authenticate an user in my app. While runing this code, the `console.log("this", isAuthenticated);` is executed (or at least shown in the console) before the const `checkLoginStatus = () => {...};`. For reference, see below.

I also tried to use the `useState`, but it also didn't work out.

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";
    import axios from 'axios'
    
    function ProtectedRoute({ component: Component, ...restOfProps }) {
    
        // const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
        var isAuthenticated = null;
        useEffect(() => {
         checkLoginStatus()
        }, []);
        
        const checkLoginStatus = () => {
            axios
                .get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/session/extend`, { withCredentials: true })
                .then(response => {
                    // logged in
                    //setIsAuthenticated(true);
                    isAuthenticated = true;
                    console.log("logged in") // second in the console
                    console.log(response);
                    return true;
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    // not logged in
                    //setIsAuthenticated(false);
                    isAuthenticated = false;
                    console.log(error)
                    return false;
                });
        };
        //checkLoginStatus();
        // setTimeout(function() {
        //     console.log("this", isAuthenticated);
        // }, 2000);
        console.log("this", isAuthenticated); // first in the console
    
        return (
            <Route
                {...restOfProps}
                render={(props) =>
                    isAuthenticated ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />
                }
            />
        );
    }
    
    export default ProtectedRoute;
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: It would be, because the auth call is async.

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks. Is there an option to synchronize it?

Comment: Isn't this code making infinite API calls when using state variable?
Well OP has updated useEffect now hehe

Comment: @ArpitParmar please take a look at my edit

Comment: Yeah I did @Mr.Hankey. Now thinking about the possible solutions to your problem.

Comment: Why you need to call checkLoginStatus in the Protected Route function? I guess protected route function is being called from other function. so you can pass authentication params or you can get it from local storage. Why you need to get authentication status from API?

Comment: After the login you have to save the state to local storage for easy access. You can't keep hitting the server to check whether user is authenticated. https://dev.to/olumidesamuel_/implementing-protected-route-and-authentication-in-react-js-3cl4 check this example.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the second console log is logged first is because axios returns a promise, and the code in the `.then` is ran only after the promise is resolved.

Simply moving the console log into the `.then` and `.catch` will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases here:

1. state variable isAuthenticated
2. local variable isAuthencticated

For case 2.:
The reason is simply that the API call was asynchronous and did not change the state of the component, the rendering happens only once and that too before the API call is executed hence second console.log statement is executed first and then the first console.log is executed. One thing to note here is that changes to isAuthenticated won't trigger a re-render with updated isAuthenticated variable.

For case 1.:
This is a very interesting case and has a very peculiar useEffect characterstic in it. After any async call inside useEffect for every state change a re-render will be triggered. What happened when you changed state variable isAuthenticated is that a re-render was triggered again and then the next console.log statement after setIsAuthenticated statement was executed. This resulted in second console.log statement getting executed, again after it did earlier in the initial render, before the first console.log statement present inside API call was executed.

A nice subreddit regarding this: https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/lhj7nb/batching_usestate_in_async_useeffect/